# Rigify Torso Twists Unnaturally

Tags: mesh, rigging, topology, rigify

I'm encountering a similar issue as to when rigify causes an arm to twist unnaturally, but at a more extreme state and on the torso with a dog rig. I have tried the recommendations in the answers of similar issues but none that I've been able to find have been successful. This includes changing the weights in the affected area, checking the bone rotations and trying to rig the model again from scratch, along with applying it to the model by each of the three end bone layers individually as well as through all the control layers at once.

I have used the same process of making the model as every other successful model I have made and had no issues like this, I have even used the same base mesh this model was created from and rigged it with no issues. [image: twisted mesh]

here is an image of how the mesh is twisting, which is caused by moving the pelvis control (no associated vertex groups of the weight painting have completely fixed the issue) The actual rig does not move out of place or unnaturally at all and only the mesh reacts strangely. The following is an image of how the mesh looks normally, to show it has no strange geometries.
[image: normal version]

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Update: I ended up using the cat rig and it was similar enough in anatomy to work out well. My recommendation for anyone else with this problem is to just switch to the cat rig.

[image]

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: I've added the blend file, thanks for letting me know how to do so.

Comment: Same problem happened to me. I switched to manual rigging and weight painting.

Comment: It's a weird one.  I think you've got some bone rolls calculated wrong but I wasn't able to figure out which ones.  Any chance that you've got a bone constraint conflicting with bone parenting?

Comment: I haven't added any restraints myself and I'm unaware of any auto generated in rigify that would have such interference.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in the default wolf armature. Set the **spine.004** and **spine.006** bones roll to zero in edit mode then generate the rig again.

Comment: It seems it most likely is a bug, but even setting the bone rolls back to zero and regenerating the rig had no different result for me.